# How to replace string in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

How to update table column having this:

`/var/mobile/233KKFSDK3234/Documents/Page.jpg`

and replace it with

`/Documents/Page.jpg`

in SQLite?

Note: All text, except `/Documents/` is dynamic.

Comment: what you have tried? where are you stuck? What are you using to access sqlite table core data or c sqlite3.h

Comment: I do not know how to replace the string which gets dyanmically generated. That is where I am stuck. Can you please help?

Comment: Why are you positing similar question again and again? Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108517/how-to-update-this-data-using-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me:

> UPDATE yourtable
>   SET yourfield = SUBSTR(yourfield,18);

..as stated by Bjoern on this question:
[How to Update this data using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108517/how-to-update-this-data-using-sql)

Comment: Didn't he say '/var/mobile/233KKFSDK3234/' is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET column = IF(
    POSITION('/Documents/' IN column),
    RIGHT(column, (LENGTH(column) - POSITION('/Documents/' IN column) - LENGTH('/Documents/') + 1)),
    column
)
```

If the pattern is found, only keep characters right of the occurrence; else, do nothing (keep old value).

Comment: Thanks for this, but '/var/mobile/233KKFSDK3234' is dyamically generated, so it is not fixed. Only thing that is fixed is /Documents/Page.jpg. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: if /Documents/Page.jpg is fixed, why don't you just set all to /Documents/Page.jpg?

Comment: My apology but all text except /Documents/ is dynamic. I have edited the question. Sorry could not explain properly first time.

Comment: No, it gives error when I run this query. I replaced COLUMN with name of the Column and table with Table Name. Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Do the string processing in ObjC and then Use this query.

```
update tablename set columnname = 'processedString' ;
```

Updated as per your requirement

Comment: My apology but all text except /Documents/ is dynamic. I have edited the question. Sorry could not explain properly first time.

Comment: You assume that the new string is Documents/Page.jpg and not any other image or string

Comment: @RonnySherer, In Sqlite you can only use SUBSTR(). Since he mentioned the entire string except /Documents/ it is not possible to use that function as well. Hence I assumed he would do the string processing in ObjC and update the column as required. But I haven't mentioned it in the answer previously. I appreciate your effort to correct it. I edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read first the string and put it in to an nsstring and then generate newstring form the old one and then update in to db.

Here you have the objective c code for generate the new string. The db update you can doit with the other answers.

```
    NSString *originalString = @"/var/mobile/233KKFSDK3234/Documents/Page.jpg";

    NSRange documentsRage = [originalString rangeOfString:@"/Documents/"];

    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithString:[originalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(documentsRage.location, [originalString length]-documentsRage.location)]];
    NSLog(@"newString:%@",newString);
```